# Socket Python 3 UDP ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, udp

I have Socket Problem

```
import socket

serverName = "herk-PC"
serverPort = 12000

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

message = input('input lowercase sentence:')

clientSocket.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'),(serverName, serverPort))

modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)


print (modifiedMessage.decode('utf-8'))

clientSocket.close()
```

This code give me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Sistem Jaringan\Task I\client.py", line 12, in <module>
    modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Any solution for my error?

Answer (score 1):

Either you have no server running at `herk-PC:12000` (UDP) or there's a firewall in between. Run the server on your local machine and have the client connect to `localhost:12000` instead to make sure everything works first.

If you still have the same kinda problems, have you used [`bind(('localhost',12000))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) on your server?

Answer (score -1):

```
#udp_client.py
import socket

target_host = '127.0.0.1'
target_port = 7210

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
nBytes = client.sendto('ABCDEF'.encode('utf-8'), (target_host, target_port))
print(nBytes, 'Bytes', 'Send OK')`
```

udp client

```
#udp_server.py
import socket

bind_host = '127.0.0.1'
bind_port = 7210

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((bind_host, bind_port))

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print(data.decode('utf-8'), addr[0], ':', addr[1])
```

udp_server

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain. What problem in the OP's code does this code solve, and how?